# Django Queryset filter for ForeignKey elements

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a problem with building a custom queryset inside one of my views.

Here is a **simplified** version of my models. The idea is that I want to track the price of different products in different shops. A **shop can have multiple products** and a **product can be present in multiple shops**. Products can have set an `is_special` flag to highlight them. The following structure was choosen because it easily allows adding new products and shops later on:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    is_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False, null=False)

class ShopProductPrice(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey("Shop", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shop_entry")
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0, null=False)

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False, null=False)
```

These are my **serializers**:

```
class ShopProductPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShopProductPrice
        fields = ['product', 'price']

class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shopProductPriceData = ShopProductPriceSerializer(many=True, source='shopProductPrice_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['name', 'location', 'shopProductPriceData']
```

And finally, here is the corresponding **view** where I want to use a **custom queryset**:

```
class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=False)
        return queryset
```

The **important point** now is the `get_queryset()` function. This is what I'm actually working on and where I do not know how to continue.
What I'm trying to achieve is to **control** with the `is_special` attribute, **if special products should be part of the output or not.**

Here are two examples of my desired outputs (the attribute `is_special` is actually not displayed here, but assume that products with name scheme **"Special Product XY"** have `is_special` set to `True`)

I'm looking for two different querysets:

**1:** A Queryset where special products are hidden in the output (shops that would have no elements in shopProductPriceData should also be not included)

```
[
    {
        "name": "Shop A",
        "location": "New York",
        "shopProductPriceData": [
            {
                "product_name": "Product 2",
                "price": 100.0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Shop B",
        "date": "Berlin",
        "shopProductPriceData": [
            {
                "product_name": "Product 3",
                "price": 100.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**2:** A queryset where special products are included:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Shop A",
        "location": "New York",
        "shopProductPriceData": [
            {
                "product_name": "Special Product 1",
                "price": 5.0
            },
            {
                "product_name": "Product 2",
                "price": 100.0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Shop B",
        "date": "Berlin",
        "shopProductPriceData": [
            {
                "product_name": "Special Product 1",
                "price": 8.0
            },
            {
                "product_name": "Product 3",
                "price": 100.0
            },
            {
                "product_name": "Special Product 2",
                "price": 100.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However, with the querysets I've given above, this is not working:

`queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=True)` actually returns all Shops which have at least one `is_special=True` product

`queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=True)` returns all Shops which have at least one `is_special=False` product.

In both cases if the shop is shown, all nested products are also shown regardless if they are special products or not.

Can you help me to come up with a custom queryset generator that produces my desired outputs?

---

Edit: Here is the working solution:

```
queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=False).prefetch_related(
     Prefetch('shopProductPrice_set', queryset=ShopProductPrice.objects.filter(product__is_special=False)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) so that the related fields are already fetched, using [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) you can also filter on the related objects.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=False).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('shopproductpricedata__product', queryset=Product.objects.filter(is_special=False)))
```

Comment: This led me to the actual solution. Thank you so much. 
I had to make a few changes. The correct solution is:

`queryset = Shop.objects.filter(shopproductpricedata__product__is_special=False).prefetch_related(Prefetch('shopProductPrice_set', queryset=ShopProductPrice.objects.filter(product__is_special=False)))`

This returns only the non-special products for all shops.